# How to solve Invalid value error in list flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I am having listview named as photoslist which contains 3 images.
I am able to print the first image of listview using photoslist.first.
But I am getting range error index when I am trying to fetch listview remaining items like

photoslist[1] //gives error invalid value range
photoslist[2] //gives error invalid value range

Can anyone explain me in detail like how can I print the remaining elements of listview.
I want to store first image in variable x , second image in variable y and so on.

Comment: add code snippet to your post.